# Live version of project not printing word documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, office-interop

I have created a program that takes a word document and prints it from visual studio to my default printer using the code:

```
//Check to see if the file exists
if (File.Exists(fileName.ToString()))
{
    object readOnly = false;
    object isVisible = false;

    //Setup Word.Application class
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document aDoc = null;

    //Set Word to invisible
    wordApp.Visible = false;

    //Open the word document
    aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    try
    {
        //Activate Document
        aDoc.Activate();

        //Find Place Holders and replace them with values

        //Dear ___
        if (Convert.ToInt32(GuestNumber) == 0)
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<NameAddressed>", NameAddressed);
        //Dear ____ and Family
        else
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<NameAddressed>", NameAddressed + " and Family");
        //Which Session they are attending
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<SessionInfo>", SessionInfo);
        //How many people are coming with them
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<NumberGuests>", GuestNumber);
        //How much they owe
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Balance>", Balance);

        //Mailing Information
        //First Last
        if (Convert.ToInt32(GuestNumber) == 0)
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<FullName>", FullName);
        //First Last and Family
        else
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<FullName>", FullName + " and Family");
        //Number St/Rd/etc.
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Address1>", Address1);
        if (Address2 != "&nbsp" && Address2 != "" && Address2 != " ")
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Address1>", Address1 + "\n\r" + Address2);
        else
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Address1>", Address1);
        //City
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<City>", City);
        //State
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<State>", State);
        //Zip Code
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Zip>", Zip);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //with the warning below, the default is correct.
        aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        wordApp.Quit(ref NoSave, ref missing, ref missing);
                                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "error", "javascript:;alert('" + ex.Message + "')");
        return false;
    }

    object copies = "1";
    object pages = "";
    object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
    object items = Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
    object pageType = Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
    object oTrue = true;
    object oFalse = false;

    //Prints out the new word document
    aDoc.PrintOut(ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    //Close the document - you have to do this
    object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    aDoc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);

    // Make sure all of the documents are gone from the queue
    while (wordApp.BackgroundPrintingStatus > 0)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

    wordApp.Quit(ref NoSave, ref missing, ref missing);
}
else
{
    litError.Visible = true;
    litError.Text = "File Does Not Exist";
    return false;
}
```

However, the function only prints the document when I have not published the project.
The document fails to open and it sends the function into the else statement:

```
else
{
    litError.Visible = true;
    litError.Text = "File Does Not Exist";
    return false;
}
```

The file string I was trying to use is:

```
fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"LetterImages\SpringOrientationDomesticConfirmation2013.docx";
```

What would be the correct string to open the file?

Is there another function or method that needs to be added for a document to print properly from the web?

Comment: Yes, MS Office needs to be installed on the computer you run it on. But I'm pretty sure the error you get would tell you that, right?

Comment: I looked into it a bit more and found that the file is not opening correctly. I updated the question

Comment: Oh, I don't know where your document is located. In the error message, replace the word "File" by the file name you're trying to open (including the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory bit). Also make sure that you really don't end up in the `catch` block. Output some diagnostics there.

Comment: It is not going into the catch. Still trying to figure out why it's not using the file properly

Comment: if the `else statement` is invoked- doesn't it mean that your file doesn'exist? I mean this: `if (File.Exists(fileName.ToString()))` return false?

Comment: @KazJaw right, it returns false but the file does exist. My problem is finding the correct path for it

Comment: don't you miss additional **\** between this two: `...BaseDirectory + @"LetterImages\...`? Should be there: `BaseDirectory + @"\LetterImages\...`?

Comment: @KazJaw I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: I mean to start the second part of the path with additional '\' like: `@"\LetterImages\...`

Comment: I tried both and it is still unable to find the file

Comment: Have you actually looked at what `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` contains, or are you just groping in the dark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Office installed on the server that is running the code.

Comment: I have the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in the References in the project. Is that what you mean or do I need to actually install Office onto the server?